# i need help getting ratchet push.js fade transition to work?

Tags: ratchet, push.js

this is a basic example calling "two.html", with the fade transition

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="medium-6 columns text-center top">
        <a href="two.html" data-transition="fade">POSPAId</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is two.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="medium-6 columns text-center top">
        <a href="index.html" data-transition="slide-out">
            back
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```